# Ubuntu 16.10 unable to Install Nodejs? Any alternative?

Tags: ppa, 16.10, nodejs

I'm currently trying to install nodejs on my system in order to use MSI's LED manager gui, however when I use nodejs's official doc on how to install I get a 404 Not found on the list.

The commands I used in terminal:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/shawn-p-huang/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shawn-p-huang/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

And I'm aware Ubuntu 16.10 is a bit new, but I had to switch from 16.4 to 16.10 because it gave me quite an amount of issues that I wasn't able to fixed until I upgraded to 16.10.

Is there currently any fix or alternative ways of installing Nodejs version 6 or above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the repository key

```
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

Then setup the repository and install **nodejs 7.3.0**

```
sudo sh -c "echo deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x yakkety main \ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs
```